# Laravel nested relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a user model which stores basic user information such as username, password etc.

There are also 3 types of user, `Student`, `Staff` and `Parent`. Each type also has a seperate model. For example, there is a `Student` model which belongs to a `User` model.

I also have a relationships table, which stores relationships between students and parents. This relationship is stored in the User model.

If I do something like:

```
App\Student::first()->user->relations;
```

It happily returns a collection of related parents.

In my `Students` model, I have a method called `hasParent()` which accepts a given user ID, and checks to ensure the student has a parent with that id. In that method, I have the following:

```
public function hasParent($parent)
{
    return $this->user->relations->where('id', $parent)->count() === 1;
}
```

However, this returns an error `Cannot call 'where' on a non-object`. If I debug further, `$this->user->relations` returns an empty array.

The problem is, like above, if I call the methods separately, I get the results I want.

So to clarify, if I run:

```
App\Student::first()->user->relations;
```

This returns a collection of users just fine.

In my `Student` model however, if I call:

```
$this->user
```

Then I get the correct student

If I call

```
$this->user->relations
```

I get an empty array. Which doesn't make sense! Can anyone shed any light on this, or what I might be doing wrong? If you need any further info, please let me know.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about relationships?

Comment: Why not using a Role Model with coresponding values student,staff,parent and relate it with User Model for this purpose? Wouldn it simplified your structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `where` on the relation like below.

```
public function hasParent($parent)
{
   return $this->user->relations()->where('id', $parent)->count() === 1;
}
```

See the parenthesis after the relations. If you call the relation without the parenthesis Laravel returns you a collection. To get the builder you need to call the relation with the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest - to avoid creating a huge query overhead (which you'll do by calling where and count on the Query builder, not the collection) - to do what you're doing already, except using Illuminate Collections `filter`-method:

```
public function hasParent($parent)
{
   return $this->user->relations->filter(function($relation) use ($parent){return $entity->id === $parent;})->count() === 1;
}
```